# Java: Which Markup Language to use for User Comments

Tags: java, parsing, jakarta-ee, markdown, markup

Which Markup Language do you use for user comments and other user generated content when building web applications for Java EE? I.e. if you were to code SO in Java, what would you use to parse the questions.

I have already found some markup languages (Markdown, Textile, BBCode, Creole...) and some of them seem to have a Java implementation, but I have not found a  well-established mainstream one (for Java). Most of the related projects don't seem to be very active. For example in the MarkdownJ forums I read "I agree with you about creating  anew implementation not based on regular expressions, and as such, there's a new ticket [...]" and users are reporting strange Exceptions.

I can't believe there's no standard solution. Is there any markup language you would usually use for Java projects? Can someone name a large web site using Java and (preferably an open source) compiler for a markup language like Markdown? Is using plain old HTML with some validation the default way to go?

Comment: Diversity is good. You wouldn't want your users stuck with a single (quite possibly unsuitable or crappy) markup language just because of the language you chose to use on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with [Mylyn WikiText](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Incubator/WikiText) as have others, but it's a specific format. IMO it doesn't matter a huge amount, particularly since a converter for essentially every syntax is available for the JVM, even if you end up switching languages.

Filtered HTML is fine, but it's a PITA to write in.

Honestly, I'd just pick one, or tweak one--I ended up using a combination of mostly-markdown, but with embeddable macros like XWiki/Confluence etc. originally pulled from the [XWiki syntax parsing](http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/XWikiSyntax) but modified. In my head I'm still working on it; in reality... not so much.

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought about using JNI to connect a Markdown C library (like https://github.com/bxt/sundownJni), but I think it's going to be WYSIWYG-created and then filtered HTML, I might use OWASP.

Comment: @amoebe Why use a C Markdown library when there's [MarkdownJ](http://code.google.com/p/markdownj/)? The extra effort can't possibly be worth it.

Comment: Extra effort? C stuff should be faster and is well tested. (I wouldn't trust the JNI parts though. ) MarkdownJ however is a port of the original crappy regex based implementation and has zero API doc.

Comment: Yes, extra effort: "the JNI parts". Interfacing to a binary. How much API doc do you need? It was all pretty straight-forward when I wrote a Struts 2 result type with it. IMO Markdown ends up not being powerful enough anyway; partially its point, but it's why most people turn elsewhere.